# Change the look and feel for a specific site

Tags: 2013, master-page, site, collection

I have a Site within a SharePoint 2013 Site Collection that I would like to completely modify the look and feel for. To my understanding, this is done in SharePoint Designer 2013, using the Master Pages tab. However, I would like to know if it's possible to make drastic changes to one Site that is within a Site Collection without modifying the rest of the Site Collection? Otherwise, I will have to migrate this Site to a fresh Site Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Each Site has a Master Page Gallery `site/_catalogs/masterpage/..`. So you can add your master page and style files into the particular site.

Then you can use Site Settings to change the Master Page instead of inheriting from the Parent (Site Collection).